# Converting a 4 rank matrix to 2 rank matrix after using tensorproduct

Tags: matrix, tensor, sympy

Let's say I have a 2x2 matrix (with symbols) called 'A'.  Now, if do

```
B = sympy.tensorproduct(A,A)
print(sympy.shape(B))
```

I get,

```
(2,2,2,2)
```

which is a 4 rank tensor.

**However, what I want back is a 2 rank 4x4 matrix.  How can I do that?**

I tried reading documentations for sympy and found out about reshape.  But it didn't work for me.  The one difference I could note was that in the examples the matrices were very simple or only had numbers.  While the matrix I am trying has some exponentials of time (a variable/symbol).

Comment: Your question does not say what kind of operation you actually want!

Comment: My question is right above the long paragraph part. I can see how people can fail to notice it though. I'll put the main part of the question in bold in a separate line. Maybe that will help.

Comment: What I was asking is this: There are many 4x4 matrices one could construct. You are asking what *function* to call, but you are not saying what *mathematical operation* you are trying to attempt, and so it is unclear which function would be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want [`numpy.kron`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.kron.html).

Comment: Wow. It never occured to me that numpy would work just fine with symbols. I knew about kron but kept looking in sympy. Thanx a lot